# Gurobi with multiple objectives

Tags: c++, linear-programming, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming, lexicographic

I am solving a multi-objective linear program with a lexicographic order in Gurobi and I set a time limit (c++ program calling the solver).

I want to retrieve the gap for the last objective that was being optimized when the time limit was reached, along with its corresponding objective number. The command `GRB_DoubleAttr_MIPGap` is yielding the following error

```
Error code = 10005
Unable to retrieve attribute 'MIPGap'
```

I cannot find any other alternatives, is it possible to retrieve these two values?

Comment: If you [edit] your question to tell us how you call the command, and the error you get, then someone might be able to help you with that.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I edited the question with the error

Answer (score 0):

Not all attributes are available when using the multi-objective optimization mode. You will have to query the primal and dual bounds in a callback and manually compute the MIPGap between them.

Here is some more information: [How do I query best bound and best objective values in multi-objective optimization?](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042858291-How-do-I-query-best-bound-and-best-objective-values-in-multi-objective-optimization-)